# RxJava operator that waits to emit until it has a subscriber

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-architecture-components

I'm looking for either a ConnectableObservable or Subject that if there are no subscribers will cache the values and wait to emit them until a subscription occurs. But if there are subscribers then it does not cache them and any new subscribers will not get previous events.

Comment: Have a look at these components: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions/blob/master/README.md#unicastworksubject

Comment: Thanks, I think I can live with Unicast or Dispatch for my use case, but why is there not a multicast version?

Comment: What do you mean by multicast version?

Comment: Multiple observers could receive events at the same time, only buffer when there are no observers.

Comment: MulticastWorkSubject

Comment: BehaviorSubject?

Comment: Not BehaviorSubject because I don't want it to cache when there is a observer.

Comment: There is no component which caches only when there is no consumer and otherwise dispatches the same items to multiple consumers. I suggest you rethink your dataflow.

Comment: The dataflow I'm looking for is the similar to the SingleLiveEvent LiveData operator described in this github thread, though I'd like to use rxjava instead and I'd like more than one event to be cached when there are no observers. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/63

Comment: @miguel did you ever figure it out? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I've been using UnicastWorkSubject with some success, though I've run into tricky activity lifecycle situations where I get `IllegalStateException · Only one Observer allowed at a time` and it's hard to debug. I've also had success using LiveData's SingleLiveEvent.